# User sensor data for a game (e.g with Arduino)

Tags: arduino, controls, gesture

i am currently researching for my bachelor thesis. I want to do something with "wearable" devices to detect and recognize different type of gestures (like finger shooting) and use those gestures to control a game (e.g World of Warcraft or a Shooter).

**My question now is:** What is the best way to put the converted data the sensors gives me into a action inside of a game. For example i fold my pointer finger like shooting a gun and this translates to the shooting key in the game of my choice.
Do i need some kind of DLL-Injection or is it far more difficult or easier than this?

I have different devices available and i could also use http://www.arduino.cc/, which should make the life a lot easier, shouldn't it?
The problem is that i don't know how exactly the work flow here would be. Maybe someone could shed some light in this area, or push me in the right direction with some links, papers or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do i need some kind of DLL-Injection or is it far more difficult or easier than this?

**Easier.**

*Really Easy:*  Some Arduino's can act the same as a USB keyboard.  The sensors would interpret gestures and generate the appropriate key strokes.

*Still Easier than DLL:*  If you add a bluetooth shield to an Arduino, you can replace a bluetooth controller.  The motions again get translated to codes that you transmit over the bluetooth link.

Comment: Awesome. I believe i have a bluetooth shield for the Arduino available. What do you mean by "you can replace a bluetooth controller"? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In Windows and Mac, you can simply use [AAC Keys](http://www.aacinstitute.org/Resources/ProductsandServices/AACKeys/AACKeys.html), which converts serial input, e.g. from an Arduino, into keypresses. When a certain gesture is recognized, the Arduino would print the corresponding character to the serial connection. The downside is that you can't hold keys, only press them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 0):

As jdr5cr says: "Really Easy"

Take a Arduino Leonardo (it act as a Keyboard and Mouse) and use the functions Mouse.begin() resp. Keyboard.begin()

With this you the choice of a number of options.

To send a keypress: (will send "w" to USB)

```
Keyboard.press('w');
delay(50);
Keyboad.releaseAll();
```

To send a keypress with modifier: (will send "W" to USB)

```
Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_SHIFT);
Keyboard.press('w');
delay(50);
Keyboad.releaseAll();
```

To send more keypresses with modifier: (will send "WOOT" to USB)

```
Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_SHIFT);
Keyboard.press('w');
delay(50);
Keyboard.release('w')
Keyboard.press('o');
delay(50);
Keyboard.release('o')
Keyboard.press('o');
delay(50);
Keyboard.release('o')
Keyboard.press('t');
delay(50);
Keyboard.release('t')
delay(50);
Keyboad.releaseAll();
```

More information about Keyboard and Mouse with an Arduino you can find here:
http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard